# correct way to use variables in ansible inventory

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

So I started learning ansible curiously and the instructor told me to experiment some variables in inventory and I tried with my little knowledge

**this is my inventory file**

```ini
[newserver]
server1 ansible_host=54.208.201.158
server2 ansible_host=3.80.57.225
[newserver:vars]
ansible_user=ec2-user
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/ec2-user/pem/safety.pem
```

and **this is my playbook file `reprctce.yml`**

```yaml
---
- name: install nginx ( play name )
  hosts: newserver
  become: yes
  tasks:
   - name: install nginx ( task name )
     yum:
       name: nginx
       state: latest
   - name: install node ( task name )
     yum:
       name: nodejs
       state: latest
   - name: starting nginx (task name)
     service:
       name: nginx
       state: started
```

when I started running these playbooks with ansible navigator it throws error as

> fatal: [server1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: no such identity: /home/ec2-user/pem/safety.pem: No such file or directory\r\nec2-user@3.95.180.175: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).", "unreachable": true}
>
> fatal: [server2]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: no such identity: /home/ec2-user/pem/safety.pem: No such file or directory\r\nec2-user@50.16.148.14: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).", "unreachable": true}

but the fact is I double checked my ssh key file and it was absolutely correct.

**I also tried with old fashioned ansible-playbook run command and the result is it actually made changes in second server and displays first server as a unreachable one and at this point I have really confused**
My guess is I could have done error in constructing inventory file , help me to find my error

Comment: You are saying: `I double checked my ssh key file and it was absolutely correct`. ssh is saying: `no such identity: /home/ec2-user/pem/safety.pem: **No such file or directory**` (emphasis mine). My experience tells me ssh is telling the truth.and that it cannot access that file on the controller where ansible is running.

Comment: Also please note that according to the general rule on SO and to the [ansible tag description](/questions/tagged/ansible) in particular, this is a question related to conection issues and not a programming question. Hence it is off-topic here. A good place to ask those is https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Don't add needed info, more specifically code or output, in comments: [edit] your question. Requirements will be the same across all stackexchange sites That being said, your comments is looking for a key called `madhu86.pem`, the one in your inventory and in your error is `safety.pem`. So I still believe what ssh is saying.